# How to hide program name on swt tooltip

Tags: java, eclipse, jvm, swt, tooltip

I am currently developing an application in Java using eclipse swt toolkit. I am deploying my application as a jar file, which is run by the Java process.

I need to show a balloon notification, for which I am using `ToolTip` from SWT library. The strange thing is, with the latest windows 10 update, the tooltip has started to show the program name at the bottom which is quite annoying. Since the host process is java, it shows *JAVA (TM) Platform SE Binary*. How do I go about hiding this program name/ give it my custom name?

[image]

This is how I am starting by application

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_162\bin\javaw.exe" -jar "C:\Desktop\MyApplication.jar"
```

I have tried starting my program as below, giving a specific name. It doesn't help either

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_162\bin\javaw.exe" -Dname=Foobar -jar "C:\Desktop\MyApplication.jar"
```

This is how I am displaying the tooltip

```
Shell shell = new Shell(display);
tip = new ToolTip(shell, SWT.BALLOON | iconType);
tip.setAutoHide(false);
tip.setMessage(detail); //tooltip description
tip.setText(heading); // this is the title of tooltip
trayIcon.setToolTip(tip);  //this is my app tray icon
tip.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Relevant Eclipse bug suggesting integration with native notifications: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=229823 (Old, but a couple of recent comments)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the name of an SWT application by calling

```
Display.setAppName("app name");
```

You should call this as early as possible in your app, before the main `readAndDispatch` loop is started.

Comment: Thats the first thing I am doing in my app. It doesn't help.

Comment: Also, I added some more details in my question. Hope this helps